# How to upload (move) the image and saveform data in minimal form

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm using minimal form (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/04/01/minimal-form-interface/) to capture user inputs and I have stuck on uploading a image(move) and saving form data using ajax. I did research for 2 days and still I couldn't fix it. it's a great help if someone can tell me how to fix this as I have only 1 day left to handover the project

```
<form id="ImageForm" class="simform" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="simform-inner">
                    <ol class="questions">
                        <li>
                            <span><label for="q5">User Name?</label></span>
                            <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text"/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span><label for="q6">Upload your image</label></span>
                            <input id="userImage" class="user-image" name="userImage" required="" type="file" /> 
                        </li>
                    </ol><!-- /questions -->
                    <button class="submit" type="submit">Send answers</button>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <button class="next"></button>
                        <div class="progress"></div>
                        <span class="number">
                            <span class="number-current"></span>
                            <span class="number-total"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="error-message"></span>
                    </div><!-- / controls -->
                </div><!-- /simform-inner -->
                <span class="final-message"></span>
            </form><!-- /simform -->
```

And here is my AJAX code

```
<script>

        var theForm = document.getElementById( 'ImageForm' );


        new stepsForm( theForm, {
            onSubmit : function( form ) {
                // hide form

                classie.addClass( theForm.querySelector( '.simform-inner' ), 'hide' );

                var formData = new FormData((ImageForm)[0]);



                  $.ajax({
                    url: 'upload.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (returndata) {
                      alert(returndata);
                    }
                  });

                  return false;

                // let's just simulate something...
                var messageEl = theForm.querySelector( '.final-message' );
                messageEl.innerHTML = 'Image Uploaded';
                classie.addClass( messageEl, 'show' );
            }
        } ); 
</script>
```